# C# bind html document with tree view

Tags: c#, html, data-binding, treeview, hierarchical-data

I am making this html editor ( using HtmlAgilityPack ) there by making changes to tree view - changes must be done in parallel to the loaded document,

what would be the best way to associate htmlNode with treeNode ( I think it would be quite the same with XmlNode ). I have some ideas, but I whant to know if there is some good solution.

Answer (score 3):

As yet nobody offered help, im posting my way of doing this, hoever, if somebody will ofer a better solution, I wil accept it.

```
    public void bind(HtmlNode htmlN, TreeNode treeN)
    {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        switch (htmlN.NodeType)
        {
            case HtmlNodeType.Comment :
                result.Append(htmlN.InnerText);
                break;
            case HtmlNodeType.Document :
                result.Append("root");
                break;
            case HtmlNodeType.Element :
                result.Append('<').Append(htmlN.Name).Append('>');
                break;
            case HtmlNodeType.Text :
                result.Append(htmlN.InnerText );
                break;
            default:
                result.Append("undefined element");
                break;
        }

        treeN.Text = result.ToString(); 
        treeN.Name = htmlN.Name;
        treeN.Tag = htmlN;

        TreeNode newTN;

        foreach ( HtmlNode node in htmlN.ChildNodes ){
            if ( node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element ||  node.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0 ){
                newTN = new TreeNode();
                treeN.Nodes.Add(newTN);
                bind(node, newTN);
            }
        }
    }
```